# Best approach to model slipstream?

Tags: physics, simulations

I am looking for a way to model slipstream effect in videogames.
The two use cases I want to look at are a simple racing game and the simulation of a peleton (a big group of road bike riders), both in 3D space.

The first idea that came to my mind was a simple 2D fluid simulation (Navier-Stokes) which has all the participants as objects in it and the wind of the environment and the wind of the movement as forces of the fluid. This may result in a pretty realistic simulation of the slipstream effect but even on modern hardware this kind of simulation can only be run on a small scale and could never be used to span over a racetrack or the course of a roadbike race. This approach also isn't able the work with height differences of the terrain.

My second idea was to create a collider behind every object and other objects inside this collider profit from a reduced aerodynamic drag. You could distort the collider to cover a bigger area when going faster, rotate the collider around the object to simulate the wind direction and with measuring the distance to the center of the collider you could even simulate the amount a drag reduction if the following object is not positioned ideally.
This seems like a really good approach for basic arcade racing games as there are not that many participants and you only want to look at the slipstream created by the object and maybe ignore the wind of the environment. If you take the cycling case, this approach doesn't seem to be that good anymore, as you have much more objects (up to 150 and sometimes even more) and you have to do this for the environment wind and the wind created by the movement as they can have a different direction.

And the third idea that came to my mind was working with raycasts. If it comes to the basic slipstream case with one object following another object, one could easily cast from every object forward and detect objects and with multiple casts you could even check if the following object is centered. But when you want to take the wind of the environment into account you would need to create pretty dense field of raycasts and every time you hit an object you need to recast the ray and so on.

All of my ideas come with a performance cost and calculating a lot of collisions and/or rays every frame is something I want to avoid.
I feel like I am missing something pretty obvious and that there has to be a much better and maybe even simpler approach to this problem.

Comment: If you are determined to do reliable results (It's going to be a lot of work), you can take a look at [Wind Simulation in God of War](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dDgyBKkSf7A).  Maybe you can get inspiration from it.

Comment: Uhh, I'll have a look at it. Thanks